# How to create an HTML form that only accepts chosen zipcodes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I would like to create a zipcode validator for a delivery service website.
(Almost like a promo code field where only the correct code will work.)

It is an HTML form on the client-side where the user can type in their zipcode and check if delivery is available in their area. 
There will be 5 chosen zipcodes where delivery is available.

This is what I've tried so far with one zipcode but it hasn't been showing any error messages.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" required
              data-msg="Sorry we do not deliver to you yet."
              data-label="Zipcode"
              type="number" name="zipcode" 
              placeholder="Enter your zipcode or address" 
              pattern="11111" required
               />
</input>
</div>
<div class="btn-wrapper mt-6">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

-If the user enters and submits the correct zip code it should take them to the ordering page.

-If the zip code is not one of the chosen zipcodes, an error message should appear below the form "Sorry we do not deliver to you. Subscribe here to be notified when delivery will be available to you." (This error message would require javascript)

-Chosen zipcodes (any number will work for now). ex: 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555

Comment: store all your zipcodes in an javascript array and the loop through each entry and see whether it matches or not. If you find a match then you can proceed with further implementation otherwise you can display error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently input pattern not supported for `number` type but it available for `text`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, and `password`

```html
<p>validate any 5 digit</p>
<form>
  <input pattern="[0-9]{5}" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>validate only 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555</p>
<form>
  <!-- or: 1{5}|2{5}|3{5}|4{5}|5{5} -->
  <input pattern="11111|22222|33333|44444|55555" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```